# "Target F# Runtime" grayed out - why?

Tags: f#, visual-studio-2015

I'm trying to change the project target runtime from F# 3.1 to F# 4.0 in VS2015 RTM, but the target runtime dropdown is grayed out:
[image]

Any reason for this? How can I fix it?

Comment: Do you have f# 4 installed? http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=48179

Comment: Yes. In the other projects in the same solution, F# 3.0, 3.1 and 4.0 are selectable from the target dropdown.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Check your fsproj file, it needs to specify the FSharp.Core reference templatized by `$(TargetFSharpCoreVersion)`, e.g. `<Reference Include="FSharp.Core, Version=$(TargetFSharpCoreVersion), Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" />`.

Some nuget packages whack the templatized FSharp.Core reference and replace it with a hard-coded package-specific version. That prevents the project system from letting you toggle the version easily.

Fix is to simply paste back in the templatized version.

Comment: Can you add a closing slash like `<Reference Include="FSharp.Core, Version=$(TargetFSharpCoreVersion), Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" />` ? VS reports an error otherwise.

Comment: @Infinum, thank you. For whatever reason, after like latkin said, a nuget package mucked up my fsproj file. Using your line fixed my project.

Comment: https://fsharp.github.io/2015/04/18/fsharp-core-notes.html gives further details about how to reference FSharp.Core in different scenarios